# Regex that matches comma separated list of 4 strings in bash

Tags: bash, grep

Im trying to write a regex function in bash where the first and third thing in the list are the same and the second and fourth thing in the list are the same.

```
grep -E "^(([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z_]*)([,][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z_]*)*)$"
```

This is my regular expression as of now. I am unsure on how to check if the first and third, second and fourth are the same. Say for example a,b,a,b matches but a,b,b,b doesnt.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite straightforward with `awk`:

```sh
awk -F, '$1 == $3 && $2 == $4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a back-reference to check that one part matches a previously captured string.

```
grep -E -i "^([0-9a-z][0-9a-z_]*),([0-9a-z][0-9a-z_]*),\1,\2$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the question restricts "things" to be alphanumeric.  Use this grep command and regular expression:

`grep -E "([^,]*),([^,]*),\1,\2"`.